# Political candidate demographics

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to answer [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/is-there-a-tendency-for-female-and-minority-candidates-to-attract-female-and-min) question about whether a politician's female / minority status increases the chance that challengers will be female or minority. The fun begins when I have machine-readable raw data, but the closest I've found is [this list of datasets](http://index.okfn.org/dataset/elections/), which do not include the races or sexes of the candidates. Anybody know where to find that?